# Mapbox Navigation Xamarin Bindings - AAR errors "does not implement interface IComparator.Compare"

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have created all my .gradle files (.jar and .aar) through Android Studio.

The .jar files compile to .dll files through the android bindings in Xamarin without any issues - and I can expand them in object explorer Visual Studio when including them as references.

My problem is with the **.aar** files.

I have the mapbox-android-core-1.4.0.aar file from the gradle in my Jars folder in Visual Studio.

The build action is set to *"LibraryProjectZip"* and under references I have included Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat which then included all other android support dependencies.

The Android Compile version is Android 9.0
Android class parser:   class-parse
Android codegen target:  XAJavaInterop1

When I build i get the following error:

Error   CS0535  'FileUtils.LastModifiedComparator' does not implement interface member 'IComparator.Compare(Object, Object)'

The official Xamarin troublehsooting says I must add the managed return to metadata which I did as follows:

`<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.mapbox.android.core']/class[@name='FileUtils']/method[@name='FileUtils.LastModifiedComparator']" name="managedReturn">java.lang.Object</attr>`

With this added it still has exactly the same error, so I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Do I need to add a partial class to Additions or is the attr> above sufficient - just using the wrong information inside it, or am I missing what the error is in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

> Error CS0535 'FileUtils.LastModifiedComparator' does not implement interface member 'IComparator.Compare(Object, Object)'

To fix this issue, try to add a partial class declaration for 'LastModifiedComparator' class and explicitly implement `IComparator.Compare(Object, Object)`:

```
public partial class DeviceService
{
    public void Compare(object a, object b)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

In your case, the method name in `<attr ...>` tag should be **Compare** instead of the 'LastModifiedComparator' method.

Check the tutorial:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/troubleshooting-bindings#possible-causes-6

Similar issue:
[error CS0535 Class does not implement interface member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40244730/error-cs0535-class-does-not-implement-interface-member)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am not sure how to add the class into the bindings, do I add it under Additions folder? What name should I give the file, and there are no classes called DeviceService, should I call that class FileUtils? - as per the class name in attr> section above? Went to the other thread there, but I still don't know what to do

Comment: Check this link, try to create another 'DeviceService' partial class to add the method.

Comment: I changed the Metadata to the following ```<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.mapbox.android.core']/class[@name='DeviceService']/method[@name='Compare']" name="managedReturn">java.lang.Object</attr>```

Then I added the class calles FileUtils.cs under Additions:
```namespace Okes.Mapbox.Android.Core.Additions
{
    public partial class FileUtils 
    {
     
        public void Compare(Java.Lang.Object a, Java.Lang.Object b)
        {
           //IComparator.Compare(a, b);
            
        }
             
    }
}```
I do not know what to add to the void

Comment: I Know have a new error (Thankfully) -- BindingsGenerator failed unexpectedly - access to path 'obj\debug\generated\src' is denied

Comment: If you don't know what to add in the Compare method, please check the related class code of the .aar file.

Comment: Thanks, I have no idea how to do that as all I have is the .aar file
The access to file path above is fixed - the file was open. I am now back to the original error .

Comment: If just adding <attr /> in metadata.xml without creating the DeviceService class, will it work?

Comment: Just tried that as per suggestion and unfortunately it is not working, same error.

Comment: The custom class name should be 'LastModifiedComparator' instead of 'FileUtils', try to change the class.